# Circuit biasing problem for differential pair circuitry

Tags: differential

How to bias this differential circuit correctly ?

Additional Information:

Vdd = 3.3V and This differential circuit is connected in negative feedback manner to a CMOS inverter.

Note: this is not homework question. I am a self-learner and whatever useful replies I get will be used to debug https://github.com/promach/frequency_trap

[image]

[image]

*Edit for clarification*
It seems like I have a similar differential amplifier as in Figure 4.54(a) below:

Why does the first term of A1 ends up as Ad while the second term ends up as Acm ?

[image]

Is the following test circuit the right way to measure open-loop gain of my Gm2 circuit block ? note: now I have asymmetrical input rather than symmtrical differential pair

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bias thusly

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJLYW6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which will **FAIL** because your opamp is non-inverting.

Comment: will FAIL because my opamp is non-inverting. ????